# How to Clear and Re-Select Items Dropdown Based on Store Filter in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, drop-down-menu, mapping

```
  const items: any = !_.isEmpty(filters["store"])
    ? [...new Set(recentFound.map(({ item }: any) => item))]
    : [];
```

I have a React application with two dropdowns: "Store" and "Items." The "Items" dropdown is initially empty and can only be populated after selecting a "Store." When a user selects a "Store," the "Items" dropdown is filtered based on this selection.

I can select items based on the filter. However, when I want to reset the "Store" filter and clear the "Items" dropdown, I'm unable to reselect items from the filtered list. Currently, I can only see the previously selected item when reselecting, and other items from the filtered list are not populated.
How to modify this code or add additional logic to ensure that I can clear the "Items" dropdown when resetting the "Store" filter and reselect any item from the filtered list.

I'd like to be able to map to the filtered list of items in the 'Items' dropdown after selecting a 'Store.' Currently, I can only do this by refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

hope below component example can help, just run StoreItems component and try change store dropdown and observe the item dropdown changes

```
import {useState} from "react";


const store = [
    {
        "storeId": 101,
        "storeName": "Store X"
    },
    {
        "storeId": 102,
        "storeName": "Store Y"
    },
    {
        "storeId": 103,
        "storeName": "Store Z"
    }
];


const sourceItems = [
    {
        "itemId": 1,
        "storeId": 101,
        "itemName": "Store X - Product A"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 2,
        "storeId": 102,
        "itemName": "Store Y - Product B"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 3,
        "storeId": 103,
        "itemName": "Store Z - Product C"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 4,
        "storeId": 101,
        "itemName": "Store X - Product D"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 5,
        "storeId": 102,
        "itemName": "Store Y - Product E"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 6,
        "storeId": 103,
        "itemName": "Store Z - Product F"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 7,
        "storeId": 101,
        "itemName": "Store X - Product G"

    },
    {
        "itemId": 8,
        "storeId": 102,
        "itemName": "Store Y - Product H"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 9,
        "storeId": 103,
        "itemName": "Store Z - Product I"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 10,
        "storeId": 101,
        "itemName": "Store X - Product J"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 11,
        "storeId": 102,
        "itemName": "Store Y - Product K"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 12,
        "storeId": 103,
        "itemName": "Store Z - Product L"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 13,
        "storeId": 101,
        "itemName": "Store X - Product M"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 14,
        "storeId": 102,
        "itemName": "Store Y - Product N"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 15,
        "storeId": 103,
        "itemName": "Store Z - Product O"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 16,
        "storeId": 101,
        "itemName": "Store X - Product P"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 17,
        "storeId": 102,
        "itemName": "Store Y - Product Q"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 18,
        "storeId": 103,
        "itemName": "Store Z - Product R"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 19,
        "storeId": 101,
        "itemName": "Store X - Product S"
    },
    {
        "itemId": 20,
        "storeId": 102,
        "itemName": "Store Y - Product T"
    }
];

function StoreItems() {

    const [selectedStore, setSelectedStore] = useState('');
    const handleStoreChange = (e) => {
        setSelectedStore(e.target.value);
    };

    return (

        <>
            <select id="store" value={selectedStore} onChange={handleStoreChange}>
                <option value="">Select a store</option>
                {store.map((objStore) => (
                    <option key={objStore.storeId} value={objStore.storeId}>{objStore.storeName}</option>
                ))}
            </select>

            <select id="item">
                <option value="">Select a item</option>
                {sourceItems
                    .filter(s => s.storeId.toString() === selectedStore.toString())
                    .map(i=> (
                        <option key={i.itemId} value={i.itemId}>{i.itemName}</option>)
                    ) }
            </select>

        </>
    );

}
export default StoreItems;
```